# Duplicate Labels & No Line Appearing in Plot in Python

Tags: python, plot, legend

I'm plotting two lines: a set of experimental data points and a mathematical model. I'm getting the experimental data to plot as expected, but the mathematical model will not plot a line (only the symbol). Additionally, I'm getting duplicate legends and despite trying some of the suggestion I've seen on the site I'm not getting to work (probably I'm not executing it correctly).

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
from sympy import Matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Stretch = [0.998122066, 1.0157277,  1.034507042,    1.052112676,    1.06971831, 1.088497653,    1.106103286,    1.12370892, 1.143661972,    1.160093897,    1.178873239,    1.196478873,    1.214084507,    1.23286385, 1.249295775,    1.266901408,    1.28685446, 1.303286385,    1.322065728,    1.339671362,    1.357276995,    1.374882629,    1.393661972,    1.411267606,    1.430046948,    1.447652582,    1.464084507,    1.48286385, 1.500469484,    1.518075117,    1.535680751,    1.554460094,    1.572065728,    1.59084507, 1.608450704,    1.626056338,    1.643661972,    1.661267606,    1.680046948,    1.697652582,    1.715258216,    1.734037559,    1.751643192,    1.770422535,    1.78685446, 1.805633803,    1.824413146,    1.844366197,    1.860798122,    1.878403756,    1.894835681,    1.912441315,    1.930046948,    1.948826291,    1.967605634,    1.985211268,    2.00399061, 2.021596244,    2.038028169,    2.057981221,    2.075586854,    2.092018779,    2.110798122,    2.128403756,    2.147183099,    2.165962441,    2.183568075,    2.201173709,    2.218779343,    2.237558685,    2.255164319,    2.272769953,    2.291549296,    2.307981221,    2.326760563,    2.344366197,    2.361971831,    2.380751174,    2.398356808,    2.415962441,    2.434741784,    2.452347418,    2.469953052,    2.488732394,    2.505164319]
Stress = [0.010526316,  0.010549481,    0.01188998, 0.011913146,    0.012594206,    0.012618915,    0.013299975,    0.013323141,    0.014665184,    0.0153447,  0.016027304,    0.016708364,    0.017389424,    0.018729923,    0.018751544,    0.019432604,    0.019458858,    0.019480479,    0.020163084,    0.020844144,    0.020867309,    0.021548369,    0.022230974,    0.022254139,    0.022278849,    0.023617803,    0.024297319,    0.024979923,    0.025660983,    0.026999938,    0.027023104,    0.027705708,    0.029044663,    0.029069372,    0.030408327,    0.031747282,    0.033086237,    0.034425191,    0.035107796,    0.036446751,    0.037785705,    0.039784099,    0.041123054,    0.042463553,    0.044458858,    0.046457252,    0.048455646,    0.051113479,    0.053108784,    0.055763529,    0.059074623,    0.061729367,    0.065042006,    0.069014085,    0.072986163,    0.077614591,    0.081586669,    0.086872992,    0.092815666,    0.099420867,    0.106680875,    0.114597233,    0.123174574,    0.132408265,    0.142301396,    0.152852422,    0.164059797,    0.177240857,    0.191079812,    0.206236101,    0.22073295,     0.238519274,    0.256307141,    0.273434025,    0.293195577,    0.314929269,    0.335347171,    0.357740301,    0.382105572,    0.406470843,    0.434785026,    0.461123981,    0.488778725,    0.516435014,    0.544088213]

c= [6.11739377e+00,   4.78409591e-04]


plt.show()
for o, d in zip (Stress, Stretch):
    d1 = d2 = d
    d3 = 1/(d1*d2)
    d3 = 1/(d1*d2)
    C11 = d1**2
    C22 = d2**2
    C33 = d3**2
    p = 4*(c[1]/c[0])*(d3**(c[0]-2))
    S11 = -p/C11 + 4*C11*(c[1]/c[0])*(d1**(c[0]-2))
    S22 = -p/C22 + 4*C22*(c[1]/c[0])*(d2**(c[0]-2))
    T112 = (d1*S11)/(d2*d3)
    T222 = (d2*S22)/(d1*d3)
    plt.plot(d, T112, 'g--^', label = 'Model')
    plt.plot(Stretch, Stress, 'b-o', label = 'Experimental')
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.ylabel('Stress')
    plt.xlabel('Applied Stretch')
    plt.title('Stress as a Function of Applied Stretch')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

plt.plot should not be included in a loop over the individual data because it work with 2 lists or 2 arrays.As a first step, i've created 2 lists for your model data, then i was able to plot it :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Stretch = [0.998122066, 1.0157277,  1.034507042,    1.052112676,    1.06971831, 1.088497653,    1.106103286,    1.12370892, 1.143661972,    1.160093897,    1.178873239,    1.196478873,    1.214084507,    1.23286385, 1.249295775,    1.266901408,    1.28685446, 1.303286385,    1.322065728,    1.339671362,    1.357276995,    1.374882629,    1.393661972,    1.411267606,    1.430046948,    1.447652582,    1.464084507,    1.48286385, 1.500469484,    1.518075117,    1.535680751,    1.554460094,    1.572065728,    1.59084507, 1.608450704,    1.626056338,    1.643661972,    1.661267606,    1.680046948,    1.697652582,    1.715258216,    1.734037559,    1.751643192,    1.770422535,    1.78685446, 1.805633803,    1.824413146,    1.844366197,    1.860798122,    1.878403756,    1.894835681,    1.912441315,    1.930046948,    1.948826291,    1.967605634,    1.985211268,    2.00399061, 2.021596244,    2.038028169,    2.057981221,    2.075586854,    2.092018779,    2.110798122,    2.128403756,    2.147183099,    2.165962441,    2.183568075,    2.201173709,    2.218779343,    2.237558685,    2.255164319,    2.272769953,    2.291549296,    2.307981221,    2.326760563,    2.344366197,    2.361971831,    2.380751174,    2.398356808,    2.415962441,    2.434741784,    2.452347418,    2.469953052,    2.488732394,    2.505164319]
Stress = [0.010526316,  0.010549481,    0.01188998, 0.011913146,    0.012594206,    0.012618915,    0.013299975,    0.013323141,    0.014665184,    0.0153447,  0.016027304,    0.016708364,    0.017389424,    0.018729923,    0.018751544,    0.019432604,    0.019458858,    0.019480479,    0.020163084,    0.020844144,    0.020867309,    0.021548369,    0.022230974,    0.022254139,    0.022278849,    0.023617803,    0.024297319,    0.024979923,    0.025660983,    0.026999938,    0.027023104,    0.027705708,    0.029044663,    0.029069372,    0.030408327,    0.031747282,    0.033086237,    0.034425191,    0.035107796,    0.036446751,    0.037785705,    0.039784099,    0.041123054,    0.042463553,    0.044458858,    0.046457252,    0.048455646,    0.051113479,    0.053108784,    0.055763529,    0.059074623,    0.061729367,    0.065042006,    0.069014085,    0.072986163,    0.077614591,    0.081586669,    0.086872992,    0.092815666,    0.099420867,    0.106680875,    0.114597233,    0.123174574,    0.132408265,    0.142301396,    0.152852422,    0.164059797,    0.177240857,    0.191079812,    0.206236101,    0.22073295,     0.238519274,    0.256307141,    0.273434025,    0.293195577,    0.314929269,    0.335347171,    0.357740301,    0.382105572,    0.406470843,    0.434785026,    0.461123981,    0.488778725,    0.516435014,    0.544088213]

c= [6.11739377e+00,   4.78409591e-04]

Stretch_mod=[]
Stress_mod=[]

for o, d in zip (Stress, Stretch):
    d1 = d2 = d
    d3 = 1/(d1*d2)
    d3 = 1/(d1*d2)
    C11 = d1**2
    C22 = d2**2
    C33 = d3**2
    p = 4*(c[1]/c[0])*(d3**(c[0]-2))
    S11 = -p/C11 + 4*C11*(c[1]/c[0])*(d1**(c[0]-2))
    S22 = -p/C22 + 4*C22*(c[1]/c[0])*(d2**(c[0]-2))
    T112 = (d1*S11)/(d2*d3)
    T222 = (d2*S22)/(d1*d3)
    Stretch_mod.append(d)
    Stress_mod.append(T112)

plt.plot(Stretch_mod, Stress_mod, 'g--^', label = 'Model')          
plt.plot(Stretch, Stress, 'b-o', label = 'Experimental')    
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15)                  
plt.grid(True)                          
plt.ylabel('Stress')                        
plt.xlabel('Applied Stretch')                   
plt.title('Stress as a Function of Applied Stretch')        
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```